# Admin approve Paperclip images before display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, activeadmin

Rails: How can I add admin approve functionality where user uploaded images have to be approved before they are displayed on their profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add a column to the user's avatar that says `admin_approved` or something similar? Since you're using ActiveAdmin, it should pick up the column (unless you've specified otherwise). You then add a check before displaying the image:

```
<%= user_images.each do |image| %>
   <% if image.admin_approved %>
     <%= image_tag image.url %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```